# How to Pass Same Modal into Partial View from View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a strongly typed partial view #1, and i have another partial view #2 that is strongly typed with same model. i have referenced partial view #2 inside partial view #1, now i need to pass the same model from partial view #1 onto #2 how can i do so?>

```
View#1
    @model Models.ContentModel.Model1
    @Html.Partial("../PartialViews/View#2", ???????)


View#2
    @model Models.ContentModel.Model1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.Partial("<filename-withoutextension>", Model)
```

`Model` is the default variable name for strongly typed Views and Partial Views.